# Forcing jQuery Validator error on Ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, validation

I currently have the jQuery Validation plugin working successfully validating the basics of my form, ie. required fields, email validation, etc; however, I am running an AJAX request on the email field to see if the email is already in use or not. So within the SUCCESS setting of the AJAX request I would like to be able to force the following error via the validation plugin: "Sorry, that email is already registered."

I've run across the "Validator.showErrors()", but am unsure how and if it will work for this scenario. Any help is appreciated.

**My AJAX request:**

```
$.ajax({
    url: urlService,
    type: 'GET',
    data: data,
    success: function(response){
        if(response === 'true'){
            // Email exist -- force validation error
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the name of your email input field:

```
if(response){
    errors = { email: "Email already in use" };
    Validator.showErrors(errors);
}
```

If `response` is true, it will thrown the "Email already in use" error on the input field with the name `email`. Also, don't forget to validate if the field is empty.